# Get list of GC content and gene length

Tags: genetic-algorithm

I want to get a table with the gene, GC content of the gene, and the gene length from 50k+ genes.

I heard that I can get this from the UCSC genome browser, but I have no clue how... Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that your question has much to do with programming.  By the way, the "genetic" in "genetic algorithm" is metaphorical only -- nothing to do with biology.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an awk script for that. Make sure the sequence of every gene is in a row.This gives you the GC content per row.

```
awk '{gsub("N","");t=length();gsub(/[GC]/,"");print int((t-length())/t*100)/100}'
```